# Sticky HTML footer not working

Tags: html, css, sticky

So I have looked at all these posts for sticky footers on here...and tried every "fix" i can find, but I still can't make my footer show and stick to the bottom of the page.  I am not sure if it has something to do with the responsive iFrame I have in the page or not - but that seems to wipe out the footer.  The closest I have gotten was to get the footer to float above the content towards the bottom, but I can't get it to stick to the bottom with the content stopping above the footer.  Any help you can give would truly be appreciated!

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'pt_sansregular';
  background-image: url(images/body_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
body,
td,
th {
  font-family: "pt_sansregular";
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:link {
  color: #FF0004;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DC7F81;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FD5F61;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  font-family: 'pt_sansregular';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000 margin: 0 0 95px;
}
.header {
  background: url(../images/Top_Pattern.png) repeat-x;
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  background: url(../images/Foot_Pattern.png) repeat-x;
  height: 95px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setIframeSource() {
    var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
    var theIframe = document.getElementById('preview-frame');
    var theUrl;

    theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    theIframe.src = theUrl;
  }
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
  html body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  #preview-frame {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var calcHeight = function() {
    $('#preview-frame').height($(window).height());
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    calcHeight();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    calcHeight();
  }).load(function() {
    calcHeight();
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/easyadminlogo.png" width="180" height="57" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <label>


            <select name="location" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()">
              <option value="http://www.saviodesigns.com/easyadmin/">Select a Module ...</option>
              <option value="../admin_cms/">PowerCMS</option>
              <option value="../news/">News Manager</option>
              <option value="../resources/">Resources/Links Manager</option>
              <option value="../blog/">Academic Portal Manager</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </form>

      </div>
      <a href="http://www.saviodesigns.com/contact.php" target="_blank" class="infolink">
        <img src="images/requestquate.png" border="0" />
      </a>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p align="center">
    <iframe id="preview-frame" src="http://www.saviodesigns.com/easyadmin/" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="yes">
  </p>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p align="center"><em> To get help and ongoing support, please <a href="http://www.saviodesigns.com/faq_support.php" target="_blank">click here</a>.
    </em>
        <p>Savio Designs Easy Admin Copyright &copy;
          <?php $then=2 007; $now=d ate( 'Y'); if ($then==$ now) echo $now; else echo "2014 - $now"; ?>
          <a href="http://www.saviodesigns.com" target="_blank">SavioDesigns.com</a>, All Rights Reserved.</a>
        </p>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code is a mess. Clean it up so you actually have a chance at spotting syntax errors and/or illegally nested tags. Also, build a proper test case. If you think your iframe may be breaking your sticky footer, make the sticky footer works *without* the iframe first.

Comment: Also, you have no opening `<html>` tag...

Comment: Why do you have styling in your HTML AND a CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

here's your code. Dont forgot to close tags when you open. change your own colors!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
body {
 font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: #42413C;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000;
}

a:link {
 color: #FF0004;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #DC7F81;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FD5F61;
}
a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds the other divs ~~ */
.container {
 width: 960px;
 background: #FFF;
 margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}

/* ~~ the header is not given a width. It will extend the full width of your layout. It contains an image placeholder that should be replaced with your own linked logo ~~ */
.header {
 background: #ADB96E;
}

/* ~~ This is the layout information. ~~ 

1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the div. The elements within this div have padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in mind, if you add any side padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the width you define to create the *total* width. You may also choose to remove the padding on the element in the div and place a second div within it with no width and the padding necessary for your design.

*/

.content {

 padding: 10px 0;
}

/* ~~ The footer ~~ */
.footer {
 padding: 10px 0;
 background: #CCC49F;
}

/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
 float: right;
 margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the #footer is removed or taken out of the #container */
 clear:both;
 height:0;
 font-size: 1px;
 line-height: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function setIframeSource() {
    var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
    var theIframe = document.getElementById('preview-frame');
    var theUrl;
    
    theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    theIframe.src = theUrl;
   }
  </script>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
       #preview-frame {width: 100%;background-color: #fff;}</style>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var calcHeight = function() {
           $('#preview-frame').height($(window).height());
         }

         $(document).ready(function() {
           calcHeight();
         }); 

         $(window).resize(function() {
           calcHeight();
         }).load(function() {
           calcHeight();
         });
      </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="logo"> <img src="images/easyadminlogo.png" width="180" height="57" alt=""/>  </div><div class="dropdown">
     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label>


<select name="location" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()">
<option value="http://www.saviodesigns.com/easyadmin/">Select a Module ...</option>
<option value="../admin_cms/">PowerCMS</option>
<option value="../news/">News Manager</option>
<option value="../resources/">Resources/Links Manager</option>
<option value="../blog/">Academic Portal Manager</option>
</select>
</label>
</form>
        
 <!-- end .header -->       </div>
  <div class="content">
        <a href="http://www.saviodesigns.com/contact.php" target="_blank" class="infolink"><img src="images/requestquate.png" border="0" /></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<p align="center">
<iframe id="preview-frame" src="http://www.saviodesigns.com/easyadmin/" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</p>


    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <div class="footer">
 <div class="wrapper">
<p align="center"><em> To get help and ongoing support, please <a href="http://www.saviodesigns.com/faq_support.php" target="_blank">click here</a>.
    </em>
<p>Savio Designs Easy Admin Copyright &copy;<?php
$then = 2007;
$now = date('Y');
if ($then == $now)
echo $now;
else
echo "2014 - $now"; ?>  
  <a href="http://www.saviodesigns.com" target="_blank">SavioDesigns.com</a>, All Rights Reserved. </a></p>
    </div>

    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks - sorry about the messy code, I was trying several different things and I kept changing/deleting things - didn't notice some of the remnants left behind/etc.

Comment: I really do appreciate your help with this (I usually don't do the coding part as much of the sales/etc.)  Is it at all possible to have the width at 100% in this set up vs. the fixed width?  This would eliminate the additional horizontal scroll bar on the bottom when the screen is maximized but the "inner" iframe page goes beyond 960...in trying both 100% or auto, then the footer issue arises again which seems to be the issue i was getting before :(  again, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I was able to figure out how to get the iframe at 100% width without it screwing up everything else - thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should set bottom to 0 and make the div available at bottom of the scroll.